# AngularJS directives data binding doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/devubegoyama/1/edit)</kbd>

Here is a simplified version of the two directives I have, `my-input` and `another-directive`:

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <another-directive>
    <my-input my-input-model="data.firstName"></my-input>
  </another-directive>
</body>
```

JS:

```
.directive('myInput', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      model: '=myInputModel'
    },
    template: '<input type="text" ng-model="model">'
  };
}).directive('anotherDirective', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    compile: function(element) {
      var html = element.html();

      return function(scope) {
        var output = angular.element(
          '<div class="another-directive">' +
            html +
          '</div>'
        );

        $compile(output)(scope);
        element.empty().append(output); // This line breaks the binding
      };
    }
  };
});
```

As you can see in the [demo](http://jsbin.com/devubegoyama/1/edit), if I remove `element.empty().append(output);`, everything works fine, i.e. changes in the input field are reflected in controller's `data`. But, adding this line, breaks the binding.

Why is this happening?

<kbd>[**PLAYGROUND HERE**](http://jsbin.com/devubegoyama/1/edit)</kbd>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `element.empty()` call is destroying all child nodes of `element`.  In this case, `element` is the html representation of `another-directive`.  When you are calling `.empty()` on it, it is trying to destroy its child directive `my-input` and any scopes/data-bindings that go with it.

A somewhat unrelated note about your example.  You should look into using transclusion to nest html within a directive, like you are doing with `another-directive`.  You can find more info here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#transclusion

Answer (score 1):

I think a little bit context as to what you are trying to do well be helpful. I am assuming you want to wrap the my-input directive in another-directive ( some sort of parent pane ). You could accomplish this using ng transclude. i.e

```
angular.module('App', []).controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    firstName: 'David'
  };
  $scope.test = "My test data";
}).directive('myInput', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      model: '=myInputModel'
    },
    template: '<input type="text" ng-model="model">'
  };
}).directive('anotherDirective', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {},
    template : '<div class="another-directive"><div ng-transclude></div></div>' 
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It works if you require ngModel

```
}).directive('anotherDirective', function($compile) {
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  require:'ngModel',
  scope: {},
...
```